# This sentence is grammatically correct if I use "skills to do sth"?

Tags: grammar

there:

Could you tell me this sentence is right: In this position, I have developed strong customer service skills to deal with disputes and communicate with customers in a calm and professional manner.

"in this position" and "skills to do sth" are two of my concerns. Do you have any idea for the sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: please explain why you think it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In this position* is perfectly valid.

I would not use *skills to [verb]* if I mean to attach [verb] to the skills.  As your sentence stands, I understand *to deal … and communicate* as attaching to *developed*; that is, you're reporting that dealing and communicating was your purpose in developing customer service skills; it's equivalent to

> In this position, to deal with disputes and communicate with customers in a calm and professional manner, I have developed strong customer service skills.

You could also say

> I have developed strong skills **in dealing** with disputes and **communicating** with customers in a calm and professional manner.

(In this case I'd omit *customer service*, because this is part of a definition of customer service skills.)

Or

> I have developed strong customer service skills, dealt with disputes and communicated with customers in a calm and professional manner.

**Afterthought:** Now I'm wondering about the difference between *skill in* and *skill at*.

Comment: Thank you anton Shewood. Your reply is very helpful. 
This sentence is from my CV. I'd like to emphasize that I have developed strong customer service skills in/during this position. Thus, I considered the sentence like this: In this position, I have developed strong customer service skills, dealing with disputes and communicating with customers in a calm and professional manner.
Later, I use “skills to do sth” to replace “dealing with …”. How would you organize this sentence to express this meaning naturally?

Comment: Again, I prefer “skill(s) in doing” over “skills to do”, but I don't know what's in this later sentence …

Comment: ok, i get it. I do agree with you using skills in.